# Mixin "with-grid-settings" does not accept a content block

Tags: susy-compass

Mixin "with-grid-settings" does not accept a content block.

Trying to solve this, searched about it, but cannot find any info.

Thanks,
Ilia

Comment: gem update // fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you might be trying to use an incompatible version of sass. If you are on Ruby 2.0, you should try upgrading your sass gem to 3.2.7.